# Нужен перевод для кнопки "Improve this question"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

В следующей плашке о закрытии вопроса отсутствует перевод для кнопки "Improve this question":

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Простите, что не в тему, но вопрос выглядит так, будто его закрыли по причине необъективности)

Comment: @Shift https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/10604/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправил. Вот строки, которые теперь переведены:

1. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14890

   > Улучшить вопрос
2. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14935

   > Улучшить ответ
3. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14877

   > Улучшить сообщение

Comment: Не совсем понятно - Вы набросали ссылок, а что они значат? Вы исправили перевод?

Comment: @Kromster это строки, которые переведены. Исправил, да.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1152464/%d0%92-%d1%87%d1%91%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-argv) также нет перевода в плашке о закрытии.

Comment: @EOF покажите скрин. У меня вроде всё переведено =/

Comment: @EOF а, вижу. Нужно было другим пользователем зайти.

Comment: @EOF добавил перевод.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Спасибо. Respect+ Вам за оперативность)